# why my ngFor failed in async array

Tags: angular, firebase

```html
     <div class="panel-body">
         {{ (currentPlatformProfile | async)?.length }} <!-- line 1 -->
         <table>
             <tr *ngFor="let platform of {{(currentPlatformProfile | async)}}">
                     <td>{{platform.infoPlatform}}</td>
                     <td>{{platform.infoGameId}}</td>
                     <td>{{platform.infoChannel}}</td>
             </tr>
         </table> 
 </div>
```

my html code is in the snippet, in fact line 1 work correctly, but in the ngFor it failed with

How could I make use of this array?

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("         {{
>   (currentPlatformProfile | async) }}
>                       
>                       ]*ngFor="let platform of {{(currentPlatformProfile | async)}}">
>                               {{plat"): ng:///AppModule/ProfilecreateComponent.html@130:24 Can't bind to
>   '*ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'.
>
> > Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you this ?

```
<tr *ngFor="let platform of currentPlatformProfile">
         <td>{{platform?.infoPlatform}}</td>
         <td>{{platform?.infoGameId}}</td>
         <td>{{platform?.infoChannel}}</td>
 </tr>
```

also in you class assign `currentPlatformProfile = []` while defining , and use `safe operator (?)` in template for avoiding errors.

> not working why ? `*ngFor="let platform of {{(currentPlatformProfile | async)}}"`

because you cannot use `interpolation syntax ({{}})` inside angular syntax

Comment: I have solve this problem in the following, but you provide an another solution, anyway, thanks.

Comment: Your welcome, anyways which solution you choose may i know ?

Comment: @ Pardeep Jain  I apply the below solution answered by myself, but your answer is definitely in deeper level.

Comment: Ohh great self answered , glad to hear about my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr *ngFor="let platform of currentPlatformProfile | async">
```

would solve this problem